# session variables lost between pages or use same variables

Tags: php, session, variables

Yesterday I learn many thing from you, especially from Marc and my problem was solved ( [session variables lost between pages or use same variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579185/session-variables-lost-between-pages-or-use-same-variables) ).

But now I continue asking: I don't want to use Session ID(session.use_trans_sid = 1) between pages. But also I don't want to use same session variables for different users at same application and also I don't want lost session variables between pages for same user.

Is it possible? If yes how?
Thanks for everybody for any help.
Best regards.

I have Wamp Server(2.2.11) with PHP(5.2.9.-2).

My php.ini's session settings at below:

```
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "c:/wamp/tmp"
session.use_cookies = 0
;session.cookie_secure =
;session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly = 
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor     = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = 0
session.bug_compat_warn = 1
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =
;session.entropy_length = 16
;session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 1
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
```

I solved this problem with setting different session_name at php script with using cookies.

Comment: So you want to store session data without using cookies or the `trans_sid` method?  Why not just use cookies?

Comment: How exactly do you test the session functionality for different users?

Comment: Dear Friends,
When I just use cookies I got a problem: Different users use same session variables at same application.
session.use_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.use_trans_sid = 1

Comment: I tested this case both FF and IE. Same session variables were used when application was started for different users at the same browser's tabs and also at a new browser.

Comment: @user222333: So you used the same browser (e.g. FF *or* IE) to test your application for multiple users in parallel and not different browsers (e.g. FF *and* IE)?

Comment: yes... I used the same browser (e.g. FF or IE) to test my application for multiple users in parallel and not different browsers (e.g. FF and IE)

Comment: @yusufakyol: Well, that’s the problem. Each window/tab shares the same cookies.

Answer (score 0):

By using `session.use_cookie=1` it will geneerate  different session id for each user.

Comment: As I understand from you, ini must be like below... Am I correct?
;session.name = PHPSESSID
session.use_cookie=1
session.use_trans_sid = 0

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do sessions is by using cookies.

```
session.use_cookies = 1
```

If you are finding that people are using other people's sessions (presumably by using a computer that hasn't been logged out), try setting a short cookie lifetime:

```
session.cookie_lifetime = 600 ; 10 minutes
```

If you are having a different issue, it would be helpful if you could give some more details.

Comment: Dear friend,
Isn't it possible to use at the same time?

Comment: Possible to use what? You aren't being remotely clear about what your problem is?

Comment: Dear Lonesomeday,
Is it possible check my old issue that I sended yesterday : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579185/session-variables-lost-between-pages-or-use-same-variables